# Filtering query by QLineEdit and updating QSqlQueryModel

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt5, qsqlquerymodel

I got a lineExdit and a tableView i want live update tableView base on typing text in lineEdit.

```
void updateTableView(QString *st)
{
    QSqlQuery * qry = new QSqlQuery(mydb);

    qry->prepare("select * from Poems where Title like ?%");
    qry->addBindValue(st);
    qry->exec();
```

Comment: You should be updating the model to get it to execute your query and return the result in the tableView. Your table view should have a QSqlQueryModel.

Comment: I already have QSqlQueryModel * modal = new QSqlQueryModel();
ui->tableView->setModel(modal); i don't know how to send the QString st

Comment: Just replace the query on the existing model. Don't call `qry->exec();`

Comment: QSqlQueryModel* pModel = dynamic_cast<QSqlQueryModel*>(ui->tableView->model()); if (pModel) { pModel->setQuery(*qry); delete qry;}

Comment: How to use lineEdit with QSqlQueryModel . Should i pass the query string via textChanget method ? Please write the answer with complete code. I'm very novice.

Comment: @BehruzMontazeri Test my answer, I have tried to give you a solution, if it does not work then show more detail of your class to be able to adapt it correctly, also do not abuse the dynamic memory.

Comment: I don't understand please explain the abuse of dynamic memory. Maybe provide me a link to study.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are abusing the pointers when it is not necessary, for example the `QSqlQuery` is creating it using the dynamic memory, and you do not eliminate it, the same with the `QString`.

Assuming that the `QTableView` model is a `QSqlQueryModel` then you should do the following:

```
...
// constructor
    connect(your_le, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, &YourClass::updateTableView);
...

void updateTableView(const QString & st)
{
    QSqlQuery query(mydb);
    query.prepare("select * from Poems where Title like ?");
    query.addBindValue(QString("%1%").arg(st));
    query.exec();
    your_QSqlQueryModel->setQuery(query);
}
```

Comment: Thanks great help. That works. Which wild card for begging and middle ?

Comment: @BehruzMontazeri `%1` belongs to [QString::arg()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#arg), and the second is LIKE's own, if my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.

Comment: I was going to mention no need for the dynamic allocation of query in my comment on the question.